# Styles do not work when I load the index file to cPanel

Tags: css

I am a newbie so apologies for what is likely an obvious issue but I have researched and could not find an answer. I have landing page index file that has the styles embedded. When I run the index file locally, it works perfectly. All the styles work and the landing page looks great. But when I transfer the file to the file manager in the godaddy cPanel, the page loads but the styles are not applied. I use fireFTP and sublime text.

Justin

Comment: Your path is probably wrong. Can you show the code where you import the stylesheet? (i.e. `<link rel="stylesheet" src"..." />`)

Comment: If it's online, can you share a link?

Comment: We need to see the `<head>` code from your index file. It sounds like your resource link is wrong.

Comment: Absolutely.It is live here: http://www.idoolocal.com/

Comment: I thought of that too but I used the bootstap link and not a local file...

Comment: I just figured it out!!!! Thank you for looking at this but I had the wrong bootstrap link!!! Not sure why it still worked locally though....